# d3 units formatting SI with rounding (nvd3 charts)

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I am using the SI units for formatting the axis using the code below. This way if the value goes about 1000 its represented as 1k, 2.4K etc.

```
d3.format('s')
```

Problem is some cases its displaying 13.47899999999k. How can I use the SI units along with rounding off to 2 decimal places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this `d3.format(".2s")`

Comment: If you try 103399 then .2s rounds it to 100k. I would at least expect 103k

Comment: In that case make it `d3.format(".4s")` and it if want 3 digits then make it `d3.format(".3s")` you can play around on this http://bl.ocks.org/zanarmstrong/raw/05c1e95bf7aa16c4768e/